# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(Datetime) from the type List<Opportunity>

Tags: apex, batch

```
Global class OpportunityStageChanges implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    Global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        //String query = 'Select id,Amount, (Select OldValue, NewValue From Histories) From Opportunity where stage <> NULL';
        //String query  = 'Select Id, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Field, NewValue, OldValue from OpportunityFieldHistory ';

        String query = 'Select Id,Name,Amount,LightiningEd__Stage_change_from_Prospecting__c    ,(Select ID, CreatedDate,OldValue, NewValue from Histories)from Opportunity';
        System.debug(query);        
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    Global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> scope) {
        List<Opportunity> opplist = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity opp : scope) {

            for(OpportunityFieldHistory opfh : opp.Histories) {
                system.debug(opfh.oldValue+'----'+opfh.NewValue+'-----'+opfh.CreatedDate );
                if(opfh.OldValue == 'prospecting' && opfh.NewValue == 'Qualification '|| opfh.NewValue == 'Closed Won'){

                    opp.LightiningEd__Stage_change_from_Prospecting__c = opfh.CreatedDate;
                    System.debug('Date Value' + opp.LightiningEd__Stage_change_from_Prospecting__c);
                    opplist.add(opp.LightiningEd__Stage_change_from_Prospecting__c);

                }        
            }
            if(opplist.size()>0){
                update(opplist);
            }
        }

    }
    Global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: the error is self-explanatory. `List` doesn't have `add(Datetime)` method

Answer (score 1):

> opplist.add(opp.LightiningEd__Stage_change_from_Prospecting__c);

Here you are trying to add the value of a field into the opplist which is not possible because opplist has a type of opportunity. You need to remove the .field and just add the opportunity.

> opplist.add(opp);